# CSS transition out after clicking input

Tags: css

Run your mouse down the input fields.
It looks nice, this is the effect I want.
Now - click-hold on a field, see how it fades dark?
Let go the mouse button and observe how it snaps back to light instantly.

I want to reverse this transition effect with the click behaviour:
It should go dark instantly and fade back to light after mouse click release.

Is this at all possible using ONLY CSS, while also retain the original hover effect?

```css
input {
  background: #aa7fce;
  border: 1px solid #4857bb;
  color: #4857bb;
  height: 24px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: background 0.5s linear 0s;
}
input:hover,
input:focus {
  background: #E2C2FD;
  transition: none;
}
input:active {
  color: #E2C2FD;
  background: #4857bb;
  transition: background 0.5s linear 0s;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="button" value="go">
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="name">
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="address">
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="phone">
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="city">
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="state">
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="country">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `transition: none` to `:active` state, and remove the transition from `:focus`.

```css
input {
  background: #aa7fce;
  border: 1px solid #4857bb;
  color: #4857bb;
  height: 24px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: background 0.5s linear 0s;
}
input:hover,
input:focus {
  background: #E2C2FD;
}
input:active {
  color: #E2C2FD;
  background: #4857bb;
  transition: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="button" value="go">
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="name">
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="address">
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="phone">
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="city">
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="state">
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="country">
```

Comment: are...are you even kidding me? I tried this already *and it didn't work*

Comment: @RozzA you probably kept the `transition:none` property in `input:hover, input:focus`

Comment: ahh, your edits show me now what I missed. Thanks alot!

Comment: @RozzA yea, forgot to mention that. When you add some transition to an element, you give that transition to all of his states (:active, :hover, ...). So, removing the `transition: none` from `:focus` means that he'll use the main transition - on focus. And adding `transition: none` to `:active` means that you'll override the main one. Hope it's a bit clearer now :)

Comment: I'm still confused by how transition inheritance works, but it works!

Comment: @RozzA [here's a simple fiddle of an example how it works](https://jsfiddle.net/L7779vsc/). Cheers